# Linux: When does Reverse Path Filtering happen?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, iptables

I know that with `rp_filter` set to 1, linux would check the route table to see whether the input packet "belongs" to this network (and drop it if not).

So when exactly does this happen? And which routing table does it look up?

- Does it use the routing policy by `ip rule`?
- When does it happen related to iptables chain? If I set `fwmark` in iptables' `PREROUTING` chain, and set routing policy for that fwmark, would it use the different routing table?

Answer (score 1):

Based on what I learnt from https://serverfault.com/a/932206/491739 and my own experimentation:

- Yes, it does use policy based routing (`ip rule`).
- It happens after `iptables` based on the fact that following sample rule works (I can see packets logged before they are eventually dropped):

  ```
  iptables --append PREROUTING --in-interface tun12 --match set --set ROUTE_TO_VPN_IPSET src \
           --table mangle -j LOG --log-prefix "Mark from VPN: "
  ```

However, kernel ignores `fwmark` when looking for reverse route, as I have learnt from https://serverfault.com/a/932206/491739, and ends up dropping returning packets for traffic routed using `fwmark` rather than an explicit IP address.
*Note* that https://serverfault.com/a/932206/491739 does contain some ides on how to enable kernel to respect `fwmark` (namely, setting the `src_valid_mark` option for the interface used to route packets using a policy) which I was not able to test because the kernel on my router does not seem to support it.